Derivative of $|\nabla \varphi|^2$ on Kahler manifold.
I have some trouble in calculating the derivative of $|\nabla \varphi|^2$ on Kahler manifold.
Let $M$ be a compact Kähler manifold of complex dimension $n \geq 2$ with Kähler form $\omega$. We consider the complex Monge-Ampère equation on $M$
$$
\left(\omega+d d^c \varphi\right)^n=f \omega^n,
$$
we look for solutions satisfying
$$\tag{0.2}
\omega+d d^c \varphi>0 .
$$
Near $O$ we have $\omega=d d^c g$ for some smooth strongly plurisubharmonic $g$. By (0.2) the function $u:=\varphi+g$ is strongly plurisubharmonic. We claim that there exists a holomorphic chart near $O$ where
$$\tag{1.2}
 g_{j \bar{k}}(O)=\delta_{j k}, 
$$
$$\tag{1.3}
 g_{j  \overline{k}  l}(O)=0 
 $$
$$\tag{1.4}
\left(u_{p \bar{q}}(O)\right) \text { is diagonal, }
$$
We have $\beta=g^{j \bar{k}} \varphi_j \varphi_{\bar{k}}$, where $\left(g^{j \bar{k}}\right)$ is the inverse transposed of $\left(g_{j \bar{k}}\right)$, that is
$$\tag{1.5}
g_{j k} g^{j \bar{l}}=\delta_{k l} .
$$
We get
$$
\beta_p=\left(g^{j \bar{k}}\right)_p \varphi_j \varphi_{\bar{k}}+g^{j \bar{k}} \varphi_{j p} \varphi_{\bar{k}}+g^{j \bar{k}} \varphi_j \varphi_{p \bar{k}} .
$$
Since
$$
\left(g^{j \bar{k}}\right)_p=-g^{j \bar{t}} g^{s \bar{k}} g_{s \bar{i} p}
$$
(which we obtain differentiating (1.5)), from (1.2) to (1.4) at $O$ we infer
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta & =\sum_j\left|\varphi_j\right|^2, \\
\beta_p & =\sum_j \varphi_{j p} \varphi_{\bar{j}}+\varphi_p\left(u_{p \bar{p}}-1\right), \\
\beta_{p \bar{p}} & =\left(g^{j \bar{k}}\right)_{p \bar{p}} \varphi_j \varphi_{\bar{k}}+2 \operatorname{Re} \sum_j u_{p \bar{p} j} \varphi_{\bar{j}}+\sum_j\left|\varphi_{j p}\right|^2+\varphi_{p \bar{p}}^2 .
\end{aligned}
$$
I have trouble calculating $\beta_{p \bar{p}}$, can you give me some hints?
